# SettingWithCopyWarning: Cannot solve

Tags: python, pandas

I have read some threads but I can not solve the problem.

I am using this code:

```
data_new=dataset_circulos[['x_tipif','y_tipif']]

A=cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit(data_new[['x_tipif','y_tipif']])
predicciones=A.predict(pd.DataFrame(data_new[['x_tipif','y_tipif']]))
data_new.loc[ : , 'predicciones'] = predicciones
centroides=A.cluster_centers_
sns.pairplot(x_vars='x_tipif', y_vars='y_tipif', data=data_new, hue="predicciones")
```

The application shows me the message below:

> C:\Users\USER-PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:376: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
>   A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
>   Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this warning, the line

```
data_new=dataset_circulos[['x_tipif','y_tipif']]
```

should instead by written as:

```
data_new = dataset_circulos[['x_tipif','y_tipif']].copy()
```

to make an explicit copy of the slice of `dataset_circulos`.

Given that `data_new` only contains two columns, `'x_tipif'` and `'y_tipif'`, your later indexing in

```
A=cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit(data_new[['x_tipif','y_tipif']])
```

is redundant. This could be more simply written as

```
A=cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit(data_new)
```